# Efeito de contornar borda de uma div, como se desenhasse "à mão"

Tags: css3, css-animations

Quero fazer um efeito de borda, que no hover de uma div quadrada, a borda é "desenhada", sai da parte superior esquerda da div, preenche até a superior direita, desce fazendo a lateral direita, retorna para a esquerda pela inferior, e sobe, completando o quadrado (como se estivesse desenhando a borda com uma caneta).

Pode ser com svg ou com puro css3.

Espero ter sido claro, qualquer dúvida me perguntem! Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usando transições com *delay*, dá pra fazer. Veja um exemplo:

```css
a { display:block; position:relative; background:#ffc; width:300px; height:180px }

a::before, a::after { content:""; display:block; box-sizing:border-box;
                      position:absolute;z-index:5; pointer-events: none; 
                      width:0; height:0; opacity:0; border:2px solid red }

a::before { border-left:none; border-bottom:none; left:0; top:0;
            transition:width .5s linear 1.5s, height .5s linear 1s, opacity .1s 2s }
a::after  { border-top:none; border-right:none; right:0; bottom:0;
            transition:width .5s linear .5s, height .5s linear, opacity .1s 1s }

a:hover::before, a:hover::after  { width:100%; height:100%; opacity:1 }

a:hover::before { transition:width .5s linear, height .5s linear .5s, opacity .1s }
a:hover::after  { transition:width .5s linear 1s, height .5s linear 1.5s, opacity .1s 1s }
```

```html
<a>Ponha o ponteiro do mouse aqui</a>
```

Basicamente criamos dois pseudoelementos, o `::before` com a parte superior direita, e o `::after` com a parte inferior esquerda.

Usamos posição absoluta nos pseudoelementos e `display: block` para garantirmos que o elemento ocupe a área toda do *parent*, que tem posição relativa, para limitar a área dos pseudoelementos.

O `z-index:5` faz com que os elementos com borda apareçam sempre por cima do elemento principal, e o `pointer-events:none` evita que eles "roubem" o clique do mouse do elemento principal.

Como as bordas ficariam aparecendo nos cantos antes da animação, usamos o `opacity` para escondê-las até o momento certo.

Finalmente, para termos a animação desenhando e "desdesenhando" na hora que o mouse sai do elemento, aplicamos `transition`s diferentes dentro do elemento, e do elemento`:hover`.

Para alterar a velocidade, lembre-se de alterar todos os tempos na mesma proporção. A animação atual leva 2 segundos. Por exemplo, se quiser que dure um segundo só, tem que trocar nessa proporção:

```
Tudo que for  .5s por  .25s
               1s por  .5s
             1.5s por  .75s
               2s por  1s

              .1s você pode manter, pois é pra ser "quase instantâneo" mesmo.
```

Basta manter a proporção para outras velocidades.

Comment: Perfeito, amigo! Muito obrigado e parabéns pela resposta.

Comment: @TiagoP.C foi um "quebra cabeças" no começo, até eu imaginar como resolver, mas acho que no fim deu pra fazer um balanço legal entre complexidade e resultado. Espero que seja útil, ao menos como exemplo.

Comment: Procurei fazer de uma maneira que você possa usar independente do tamanho do elemento, e que aceite espessuras de borda conforme você achar melhor (desde que não seja muito espessa), mas se tiver alguma duvida em algum ajuste extra, comente aqui.

Comment: Isso é mágica. :)

Comment: Depois vou analisar esse código com calma, ótima solução