# Pintar parcialmente a borda em CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma em css ou até mesmo JavaScript de preencher apenas uma parte da borda por vez, como se fosse uma animação em que a borda é preenchida aos poucos e ter o controle de quanto é preenchido.
Exemplo:

[image: exemplo de borda sendo preenchida]

A ideia é preencher a borda aos poucos com cada ação que o usuário fizer.

Cheguei a uma solução graças ao @hugocsl

CSS

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 1.5s;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
svg,
svg rect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: transparent;
}
#svg #rect {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
  transition: all 500ms;
  stroke-dasharray: 320;
  stroke-dashoffset: 320;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg id="svg">
    <rect id="rect"></rect>
  </svg>
  Btn
</a>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Mudar" onclick="mudar(start)"/><br/>
```

Javascript

```
var dasharray = document.getElementById("svg");
start = 320;
dasharray.style.strokeDasharray = start;

function mudar(start){
    var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
    var rect = document.getElementById("rect");

    this.start = start - 20;
    if(this.start < 0){
        this.start = 320;
    }
    
    svg.style.strokeDashoffset = rect.style.strokeDashoffset = this.start;
    
};
```

Sempre que houver uma ação do usuário a borda será preenchida, coloquei apenas o apertar de um botão como exemplo.

Comment: Relacionado: [Efeito de contornar borda de uma div, como se desenhasse “à mão”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151029/70) e [Borda incompleta com CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168613/70)

Comment: Não edite a pergunta e coloque a reposta na pergunta, crie uma resposta e responda a sua própria pergunta.

Comment: Você disse: "A ideia é preencher a borda aos poucos com cada ação que o usuário fizer."

A solução para essa questão não é simples. Na verdade é um belo desafio.

Algumas premissas são indispensáveis, caso contrário a solução torna-se extremamente complexa.
1) A ação do usuário deve estar bem definida: Por exemplo: Definir número de clicks (N) dentro do DIV que receberá a borda animada. A cada click a borda vai crescendo 1/N.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Existem algumas formas diferentes de fazer isso, vou propor 2, uma com SVG que de longe é a opção mais indicada. A outra vc vai precisar construir cada "borda" individualmente e fazer um CSS um pouco mais extenso para tratar cada uma dessas bordas individuais.

**Opção 1 SVG**

Essa opção pode intimidar no início pous usa propriedades do SVG, porém essas propriedades são animadas pelo CSS o que facilita muito o entendimento.

É apena um `svg rect` dentro do link com 100% de altura e largura dentro desse link

```
<svg>
    <rect></rect>
</svg>
```

O principal é ter em mente que as propriedade `stroke-dasharray` e `strok-dashoffset` o pontilhamento da linha da borda no que se refere ao tamanho do pontilhado e a distancia entre um pontilhado e outro. A ideia é ter 1 pontilhado do tamanho do Btn, e um `offset` tb do tamanho do Btn, e com o CSS a gente controla essa transição Zerando o  tamanho do `offset` no `hover`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para entender melhor veja o código. Imagine que é apenas 1 `dashoffset` (espaço vazio) que vai ocupar o BTN inteiro, e depois com 1 `dash` vamos fazer a borda do botão inteiro.

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 1.5s;
  position: relative;
}
svg,
svg rect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  fill: transparent;
}
a svg rect {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
  transition: all 500ms;
  stroke-dasharray: 320;
  stroke-dashoffset: 320;
}
a:hover svg rect {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <svg>
    <rect></rect>
  </svg>
  Btn
</a>
```

---

**Opção 2 HTML/CSS**

Como falei no início vc vai precisar de um elementos para cada "borda". Além disso vc precisa fracionar os valores da transição para a animação ficar bem casada. E usar a regra `:hover` e `:not(:hover)` para fazer a animação ir e voltar. É um CSS um pouco mais extenso, mas não é muito complexo...

**Execute o código abaixo**

```css
.subcont {
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
  background: purple;
}

.border1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.border2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.border3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.border4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcont:hover>.border1 {
  height: 190px;

}
.subcont:not(:hover)>.border1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;

}

.subcont:hover>.border2 {
  width: 255px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.subcont:not(:hover)>.border2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcont:hover>.border3 {
  height: 190px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.subcont:not(:hover)>.border3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcont:hover>.border4 {
  width: 255px;
}
.subcont:not(:hover)>.border4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="subcont">
    <div class="border1"></div>
    <div class="border2"></div>
    <div class="border3"></div>
    <div class="border4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante, mas eu também queria ter o controle de quantos % da borda é pintado. Então eu vou estudar o código que você passou e tentar adaptar, pois quero colocar o valor do quanto é pintado dinamicamente.

Comment: @HelvioFilho que porcentagem é essa que vc quer mudar? A largura do traço, tipo a largura do borda é isso? Se for na opção com SVG basta vc  ajustar o `stroke-width: 4;` no `rect` e na outra opção vc precisa ajustar o `height: 5px;` e `width: 5px;` na classes `border1 2 3 4` Se for sobre o comprimento da borda ai no SVG vc pode brincar com esse valor `a:hover svg rect {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}`

Comment: eu acabei de postar como ficaria a resposta, só fiquei com uma dúvida, como você chegou ao valor `stroke-dasharray: 320;` ? No mais muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @HelvioFilho eu tinha uma "formula" mas não lembro onde salvei isso Pq uso pouco rss, mas de qq forma o ajuste fino sempre faço pelo devtools mesmo. Só tenha em mente que antes do hover os dash tem o mesmo valor, e no hover 0, e esse valor do dash sempre vai variar dependendo do width e height do elemento, quanto maior o elemento maior o valor dos dash. []'s

Comment: Muito bom seu código! Parabéns!

Comment: @AndreiCoelho muito obrigado pelas palavras meu amigo. Essa eh a verdadeira gratificação :)

Comment: Como posso deixar isso automático para usar como um preloader?

Comment: @LucasCoelho olha aqui nessa resposta tem um modelo com exemplo e explicação https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296506/como-fazer-um-spinner-puro-em-css/341189#341189 se te servir curte lá ;)

Answer (score 5):

```css
a.bordaAnimada {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: Tomato;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
a.bordaAnimada:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
a.bordaAnimada:hover:after {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="bordaAnimada" href="">Um texto qualquer</a>
```

> Fonte: [Pure CSS Animated Border | CSS Border Animation Tutorial | codeFX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQ3Y6lAESt0)

Answer (score 5):

Criei uma versão HTML + CSS + JavaScript para animar a borda de um BOX por clicks.
A versão é:

- responsiva
- válida para quaisquer dimensões do BOX
- válida para número de clicks >= 4

Se você preferir poderá interagir com essa versão no JSBin em
**http://output.jsbin.com/nivobep/**

```js
let numeroClicks = 8; // Defina aqui um número de clicks >= 4 

// Mensagem inicial dentro do div#principal
let msg = document.querySelector("#msg");
msg.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "&#129299; Dê <span style='font-weight:bold;color:red'>" + numeroClicks + "</span> clicks sucessivos<br>dentro deste DIV.");

let arr = [ ]; // Nesse array serão armazenados 4 números que definem as quantidades de clicks em cada borda
let divisao = numeroClicks / 4; // Expressa a divisão do número de clicks por 4
let inteiroDivisao = a = Math.trunc(divisao); // Parte inteira da divisão, valores possíveis = 1,2,3,4,5,... 
let restoDivisao = divisao - inteiroDivisao; // Valores possíveis = 0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75

switch(restoDivisao) { // Cria arrays que armazenam as quantidades de clicks em cada borda
   case 0: // Se o resto da divisão for 0 a quantidade de clicks será igual em cada borda (inteiroDivisao = a)
    arr = [a, a, a, a];
    break;    
  case 0.25: // Se o resto da divisão for 0.25 a quantidade de clicks na borda de cima será de uma unidade maior que nas demais bordas
    arr = [a+1, a, a, a];
        break;    
  case 0.5:  // Se o resto da divisão for 0.5 a quantidade de clicks na borda de cima e de baixo será uma unidade maior que nas bordas direita e esquerda
    arr = [a+1, a, a+1, a];
    break;
  case 0.75:   // Se o resto da divisão for 0.75 a quantidade de clicks na borda esquerda será uma unidade menor que nas demais bordas
    arr = [a+1, a+1, a+1, a];
       break;  
}

const divPrincipal = document.querySelector('#principal');
const divCima = document.querySelectorAll('.cima')[0];
const divDireita = document.querySelectorAll('.direita')[0];
const divBaixo = document.querySelectorAll('.baixo')[0];
const divEsquerda = document.querySelectorAll('.esquerda')[0];
const larguraBox = divPrincipal.offsetWidth;
const alturaBox = divPrincipal.offsetHeight;

let i=0; // Contador de clicks

divPrincipal.addEventListener('click', function() { // Função a ser executada a cada click dentro do div#principal
  i++;
  msg.innerHTML = "<span style='border: 1px solid black;background:red;color:white;padding:1px 4px;'>" + i + "</span>"; // Mostra o número de clicks

  switch(true) {
    case ( i <= arr[0]):
      incrementarBordaCima();
        break;
  }
  switch(true) {
    case ( arr[0] < i && i <= arr[0] + arr[1] ):
      incrementarBordaDireita();
        break;
  }
  switch(true) {
    case ( arr[0] + arr[1] < i && i <= arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] ):
      incrementarBordaBaixo();
        break;
  }
  switch(true) {
    case ( arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] < i && i <= arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] ):
      incrementarBordaEsquerda();
        break;
  }
  if(i === numeroClicks + 1) { // Um click a mais reseta as bordas ao estado inicial
    divCima.style.width = "0";
    divBaixo.style.width = "0";
    divDireita.style.height = "0";
    divEsquerda.style.height = "0";
    divCima.style.transition = 'width 1s';
    divBaixo.style.transition = 'width 1s';
    divEsquerda.style.transition = 'height 1s';
    divDireita.style.transition = 'height 1s';
    i=j=k=l=0;
    msg.innerHTML = "&#129299; Dê <span style='font-weight:bold;color:red'>" + numeroClicks + "</span> clicks sucessivos<br>dentro deste DIV.";
  };
});

// Funções de crescimento das bordas
j=k=l=0; // conta os clicks nas bordas direita (j), de baixo (k) e esquerda (l)
function incrementarBordaCima() {
  divCima.style.width = i * (1 / arr[0])*100 + "%"; // crescimento (em porcentagem) da borda de cima a cada click
  divCima.style.transition = 'width 0.5s';
}
function incrementarBordaDireita() { 
  j++;
  divDireita.style.height = j * (1 / arr[1])*100 + "%"; // crescimento (em porcentagem) da borda direita a cada click
  divDireita.style.transition = 'height 0.5s';
}
function incrementarBordaBaixo() {
  k++;
  divBaixo.style.width = k * (1 / arr[2])*100 + "%"; // crescimento (em porcentagem) da borda de baixo a cada click
  divBaixo.style.transition = 'width 0.5s';
}
function incrementarBordaEsquerda() { 
  l++;
  divEsquerda.style.height = l * (1 / arr[3])*100 + "%"; // crescimento (em porcentagem) da borda esquerda a cada click
  divEsquerda.style.transition = 'height 0.5s';
  if(l == arr[3]) {
    msg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", " &#128587; Mais um click para<br>resetar as bordas."); // Mensagem ao último click
  }
}
```

```css
  body {
  font: 18px sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #e9f3f8;
  }
  #principal { 
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px; /* Altere à vontade */
  height: 100px;  /* Altere à vontade */
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #302c2c;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
}  
.borda {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}  
.cima {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px; /* largura da borda de cima */
}
.direita {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px; /* largura da borda direita */
  height: 0;
}
.baixo {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px; /* largura da borda de baixo */
}
.esquerda {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px; /* largura da borda esquerda */
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Borda dinâmica</title>
  </head>
<body>

<div id="principal">
  <p id="msg"></p> <!-- Container para as mensagens dentro do DIV -->
  <div class="borda cima"></div>
  <div class="borda direita"></div>
  <div class="borda baixo"></div>
  <div class="borda esquerda"></div>
</div>

<h2>Instruções</h2>
<p>No código fonte da página altere à vontade:</p>
<ul>
  <li>As dimensões do box ( <code>width</code> e <code>height</code> ) nas CSS,</li>
  <li>O número de clicks na variável JavaScript <code>numeroClicks</code><br>
  O valor default do <code>numeroClicks</code> foi definido como 8.</li>
</ul>
<dl>
  <dt>Notas:</dt>
    <dd>A página é responsiva e todo o código fonte foi comentado.</dd>
    <dd>O script foi criado para <code>numeroClicks >= 4</code>.</dd>
    <dd>Quer praticar? Crie o script para preencher as bordas com 1, 2 ou 3 clicks.</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```